# Finding the biggest and smallest values with most counts in histogram

Tags: vb.net, text, histogram

I built a program to create a text based histogram from an image.
Now I need to pick up the data from the text file and find the biggest value with most counts and the smallest value with most counts.
This is an example from a generated text file:

```
0 1 
1000 80 
10004 2 
10005 200 
10006 2  
1002 73 
105 10
```

On the left, I have listed the pixel values and on the other side the counts.

So, here I get the value `10005` as the biggest with the highest count (`200`) and the value `1000` as the smallest with the highest count (`80`).

I know how to read the text file line by line, split the values and put them in an array.
The question is, how can I get what I want by the fastest way assuming that I'm working with large images generating long lists of values (hundreds) in the histogram text files?

Comment: Why isn't 1000 (80) the smallest with the highest?

Comment: You're right, thanks! I was more focused on the question than the list when I wrote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of minimum and maximum value is somewhat controversial here, but, following the description, the underlying logic could be that a minimun can be determined when a maximum has been found.

So, we could order the list (some hundreds lines of data is not really much) by descending (higher values first), evaluate a maximum value and, after that, determine the minimum:

```
Dim bitmapData = File.ReadAllLines("[Data File Path]").
                    Select(Function(bd) bd.Split(New String() {" "c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).
                    Select(Function(n) Integer.Parse(n)).ToArray()).
                    OrderByDescending(Function(value) value(0)).ToList()


Dim max() As Integer = bitmapData(0)
Dim min() As Integer = {bitmapData(0)(0), 0}

For i As Integer = 1 To bitmapData.Count - 1
    If bitmapData(i)(1) > max(1) Then
        If bitmapData(i + 1)(0) < bitmapData(i)(0) Then
            max = bitmapData(i)
        End If
    ElseIf bitmapData(i)(0) < max(0) Then
        If bitmapData(i)(1) >= min(1) Then
            min = bitmapData(i)
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Using your data sample and a comparison array of values, the results are:

```
Min ( 1030, 251)     Min ( 1000,  80)
Max (10001, 260)     Max (10005, 200)
--------------------------------------------
      0   1                0   1 
  10001 260             1000  80 
   1000  80            10004   2 
  10004   2            10005 200 
  10005 200            10006   2  
  10006   2             1002  73 
   1002  73              105  10
    105  10
     50 250
     51 220
   1026 201
   1030 251
   1031 250
  10009 252
  10008 250
  10007 251
```

---

Assuming that the data source is represented by two different arrays (named **`Pixels`** and **`Counts`**, here) which need to be *synchronized* (paired indexed values), you just need to substitute the **`BitmapData`** array with the `Pixels`and `Counts` array:

```
Dim Pixels As Integer() = [Integer Source]
Dim Counts As Integer() = [Integer Source]

Dim max() As Integer = {Pixels(0), Counts(0)}
Dim min() As Integer = {Pixels(0), 0}

For i As Integer = 1 To Pixels.Count - 1
    If Counts(i) > max(1) Then
        If Pixels(i + 1) < Pixels(i) Then
            max = {Pixels(i), Counts(i)}
        End If
    ElseIf Pixels(i) < max(0) Then
        If Counts(i) >= min(1) Then
            min = {Pixels(i), Counts(i)}
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thanks it works! and how can I do the same thing but taken the values from two integer arrays, one containing the pixel values and another for the counts? not reading a text file.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I have the pixels array and counts array values paired. For example: Counts(0) corresponds to Pixels(0) and so on, but in the first code that you posted, you used an OrderByDescending function and it does not exist here, and when I read the max value it throws me a "0" because it's the first number in Pixels array (index 0), and it's not in order. I have already declared these arrays, and I don't understand why you put [Integer Source] in the declaration, it throws me an error, plus I have to change  bitmapData.Count to Pixels.Count in the loop.

Comment: `Dim Pixels As Integer() = [Integer Source]` means that the `Pixels` array is filled with whatever source you use. Same for the `Count` array. If you already have a `Pixels` array (with whatever name), then use it instead. `bitmapData` has no use if you already have 2 arrays. Use just the second code snippet, where you provide your `Pixels` and `Count` arrays. The order doesn't matter here.